# Adjust Reveal.initialize from YAML in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, reveal.js

I have a revealjs presentation made in Rmarkdown with this YAML header:

```
---
title: "My title"
author: "My name"
date: November 20, 2018
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
      css: styles.css
---
```

It works perfectly but now I would like to adjust `width` in `Reveal.initialize`. Right now I'm doing it directly in the html that generates the Rmarkdown, almost at the end of the file:

```
// Full list of configuration options available at:
// https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
Reveal.initialize({
    width: 1000,
    // Push each slide change to the browser history
    history: true,
    // Vertical centering of slides
    center: false,
    // Transition style
    transition: 'default', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom
    // Transition style for full page slide backgrounds
    backgroundTransition: 'default', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom
```

What I would like is to be able to do it from the YAML of the Rmarkdown. I've tried it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
---
title: "My title"
author: "My name"
date: November 20, 2018
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
      css: styles.css
  revealjs::revealjs_config:
      width: 1200
---
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found the right way to do it:

```
---
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    css: styles.css
    reveal_options:
      width: 1200
---
```